# yandex-qatools postgresql-embedded. Does it need to have postgres installed on machine?

Tags: spring, postgresql, junit

Dependency used : ru.yandex.qatools.embed postgresql-embedded-2.5.jar

code :

```
final File dbDir = new File("/tmp/embeddedinstallation" + port);
 String postgresInfo = embeddedPostgres.start(EmbeddedPostgres.cachedRuntimeConfig((dbDir).toPath()), "localhost", port, "db", "uname", "psswd", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1209)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.Downloader.downloadInputStream(Downloader.java:127)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.Downloader.download(Downloader.java:69)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.PostgresArtifactStore.checkDistribution(PostgresArtifactStore.java:66)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Starter.prepare(Starter.java:56)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Starter.prepare(Starter.java:49)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.embed.postgresql.EmbeddedPostgres.start(EmbeddedPostgres.java:139)
    at com.ge.data.gold.MockDbServer.startDbOnPort(MockDbServer.java:210)
    at com.ge.data.gold.MockDbServer.initPostgres(MockDbServer.java:184)
    at com.ge.data.gold.GoldUtil.setupTestEnv(GoldUtil.java:25)
```

Refer : https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded

It doesn't mention that postgres needs to be installed in machine.
But I see code accessing commands :

```
package ru.yandex.qatools.embed.postgresql;

import ru.yandex.qatools.embed.postgresql.config.PostgresConfig;
    public enum Command {
        Postgres("postgres", PostgresExecutable.class),
        InitDb("initdb", InitDbExecutable.class),
        CreateDb("createdb", CreateDbExecutable.class),
        PgCtl("pg_ctl", PgCtlExecutable.class),
        Psql("psql", PsqlExecutable.class),
        PgDump("pg_dump", PsqlExecutable.class),
        PgRestore("pg_restore", PsqlExecutable.class),
        Createuser("createuser", PsqlExecutable.class),
        ;
```

Does it need to have postgres installed on machine or am I doing something incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out and it does download postgres to specified location.

```
/**
 * Initializes runtime configuration for cached directory.
 * If a provided directory is empty, postgres will be extracted into it.
 *
 * @param cachedPath path where postgres is supposed to be extracted
 * @return runtime configuration required for postgres to start
 */
public static IRuntimeConfig cachedRuntimeConfig(Path cachedPath) {
    final Command cmd = Command.Postgres;
    final FixedPath cachedDir = new FixedPath(cachedPath.toString());
    return new RuntimeConfigBuilder()
            .defaults(cmd)
            .artifactStore(new PostgresArtifactStoreBuilder()
                    .defaults(cmd)
                    .tempDir(cachedDir)
                    **.download(new PostgresDownloadConfigBuilder()
                            .defaultsForCommand(cmd)
                            .packageResolver(new PackagePaths(cmd, cachedDir))
                            .build()))**
            .build();
}
```